# Flutter error: the getter 'AudioPlayerState' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-player

I have imported audioplayer.dart but it is still showing me the error: the getter 'AudioPlayerState' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
_audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((event) {
  if (event == AudioPlayerState.PLAYING) {
    _isPlaying = true;
  } else {
    _isPlaying = false;
  }
  setState(() {});
});
```

Comment: Hi There. This is not the code that is causing the issue. Post your full code.

Answer (score 4):

```
  if (event == PlayerState.PLAYING) {
```

Answer (score 1):

in the updated version of audioplayers package, the values of PlayerState are in small case.

so PlayerState.PLAYING is now PlayerState.playing

also a few functions' names have been updated, like onAudioPositionChanged is now changed to onPositionChanged, but its working is just the same.

Answer (score 0):

to solve your problem you can do this

```
   class AudioManager {

  static final AudioManager _instance = AudioManager._internal();

  factory AudioManager() => _instance;

  AudioManager._internal() {
    player.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      _isPlaying = (state == PlayerState.playing);
    });
  }

  final AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

  bool _isPlaying = false;

  void play(String asset) {
    if (!_isPlaying) {
      player.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.loop);
      player.play(AssetSource(asset));
    }
  }

  void stop() {
    player.stop(); 
  }

}
```

make sure you have imported
audioplayers.dart';
like this

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
```

and to use it you can just

```
    final audioManager = AudioManager();

    audioManager.play("assets/music.mp3");

    audioManager.stop();
```